# Page speed and Google Swiffy

Tags: html, flash, html5-canvas, google-swiffy

I have heavy flash banners in my sites. Normally I used flash loader to decrease the page loading time.

Now, I want to use Google Swiffy and create HTML5 animation, but the file size is 700K, Is there is any trick to mage the page load faster so the user would not need to download so much data?

Comment: You really should look into making it in Canvas at this point. Look into something like CreateJS http://www.createjs.com/

Comment: In my experience a swiffy file is about twice the Kb of an SWF. Also, I can't find the swiffy release notes page anymore, but last time I checked there was sound on mobiles (if you're using audio).

Comment: If you're not already using gzip compression, do it. It helps somewhat.